# What is the proper way to speak in the present tense?

Tags: grammar

Today I'm going to school.

今日、学校に いく。
今日、学校に いって。
今日、学校に いって　いる。

I know last phrase is right, but his meaning is expressing a present in action in that moment. How can i express a more neutral present? I have seen examples of use of both the first and second cases, but I have been told that the first is not a good example, since it is a present future, non past, that is used in specific cases that are not what I am looking for.

Comment: At least grammatically, *I'm going to school* is not in the present tense either. Anyway I guess the answer to your question depends on verbs. You may want to add examples and elaborate on what exactly your question is.

Comment: 今日、学校に いっている sounds more like you are saying someone has gone to school as an explanation for why they are not home at the moment. For いっている to be interpreted as a progressive action, the time span of 今日 is too long. 今日、学校に いく is generally a better transition for your English sentence. In any case, I don't understand what you mean by "neutral present".

Comment: @sundowner present progressive vs simple present - so by present tense you mean simple present? idk that's what i remember from english class

Comment: @BCLC yes, although it could be vague for some verbs (知っている is not really progressive).

Answer (score 1):

"I'm going to school" is an ambiguous English sentence; it can mean either "I will go to school (in the near future)" or "I am on the way to school (now)". See [Present continuous for future arrangements](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous-future-arrangements/). When the original sentence is already ambiguous, it's usually impossible to find a single Japanese translation that is equally ambiguous and covers both meanings.

If you mean "I will go to school (in the near future)", the correct Japanese sentence for it is 今日は学校に行く. If you mean "I am on the way to school (now)", the correct sentence is 今学校に行っている.

今日学校にいって is a request ("Go to school today!") rather than a description.